# what exactly is this component and what the marking on it means?

Tags: coil

my car stereo (audi rns-e) showed a blank white screen, took it apart and the outer part of this component was rattling around. i want to replace it to see if it was the problem, but i dont really know what this actually is. looks like a coil or inductor, but googling the marking i got no results.

[image: picture]

Comment: more than 2 or 3 connections indicate that it may be a transformer

Comment: That's a custom made transformer. Most likely the specs are not publicly available so you can't find a replacement unless you use an identical radio for spares. Even if the transformer did have a plastic part loose, it does not mean that part is electrically broken and reason for the unit not to work.

Comment: so it goes straight to the trashcan i guess lol

Comment: It’s a special transformer part of the power supplies

Answer (score 2):

It's either a transformer or common-mode choke. Try putting the shield part back on and see if the panel will work again. If so, some glue and you'd be good to go.

Comment: tried that (w/o glue), unfortunately it didnt work

Comment: Probably then the component overheated and has an open wire, which may be why the shield fell off (melted its glue.) This Q will probably be closed as a 'repair' question however, which (and I don't agree) is off-topic. Repairing things is a great way to learn about them.

Comment: If you can identify the IC (IC801) that's next to it there may be a reference design that goes with it, which would include the transformer. In all likelihood though more stuff is fried than just the inductive element. Maybe time to visit a junkyard...

Comment: thnaks for the help, im looking into it